# Why an optional process could not be predictable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We know that a predictable process is also optional (*).

Why an optional process could not be predictable ? Why we cannot use the same arguments as the proof for (*) ?

Comment: See the second part of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/694235/

Comment: (from the discussion on this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694235/proof-that-the-predictable-sigma-algebra-is-also-generated-by-continuous-and-ada) Saz answer point 2)  Let $X$ a right continuous and adapted process then, if we set : $$Y_t^n := n \int_t^{t+1/n} 1_{|X_{s}| \leq n} X_{s} \, ds,$$ why $Y_t^n$ is not adapted ? it is continuous (because $(1_{|X_{s}| \leq n} X_{s})_s$ is bounded and measurable) ... no ?

Comment: I explain a little bit more my question : If $X$ is right continuous process and adapted, $X$ is $F_+$-measurable  and $F_+=F$ hence $X$ is $F$-adapted ? Then $Y^n$ is $F$-adapted ?

Comment: Since the integrand $1_{\{|X_s| \leq n\}} X_s$, $s \in (t,t+1/n)$ is (in general) not measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$, we can hardly expect that the integral $\int_t^{t+1/n} 1_{\{|X_s| \leq n\}} X_s \, ds$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.